# Get the array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which comes from ajax as post now I want to save each element in a separate variable

```
Array
(
['family'] => Viga
['category'] => sans-serif
['variants'] => Array
    (
        [0] => regular
    )

['subsets'] => Array
    (
        [0] => latin
    )
)
```

Now I want it to be like as

```
$family = viga
$category = sans-serif
```

Comment: And what you have tried so far? Post your attempts too.

Comment: So what about variants and subsets? $variants0,$variants1,..., $subsets0,$subsets1,...?

Comment: foreach($font as $fontDetails){
  
   echo $fontdetails->category;
  
  }@Uchiha

Comment: that has to be exploded with coma i think@Thamilan

Comment: Don't post your questions update in comments instead edit your question and be specific about your outputs @Ranjith

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php). But since you have some multi-dimensional data, which you want to implode using `,` you can use like this:

[DEMO](https://eval.in/599997)

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)) {
        ${$key} = implode(",",$value); //Join array values using ,
    } else {
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
}

echo $family;
echo $category;
echo $variants;
echo $subsets;
```

**Result:**

```
Viga
sans-serif
regular
latin
```

---

Using [Extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php), it would be as simple as:

```
extract($data);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/599998)

Comment: The answer is good, just bear in mind, that if you use "foreach solution" and try to extract by imploding values that are arrays (such as 'a'=>array(1,'b'=>array(1,2))), your code will crash.

Comment: But OP is interested with 1 depth array. Incase of multi-depth, he needs to specify the rules and then this might need some recursive calls (if needed)

Comment: Says undefined variable family@Thamilan

Comment: Have you changed the array? Create an eval so that I can check

Comment: this is the response i'am getting

Comment: Array
    (
         ["family"] => ABeeZee
         ["category"] => sans-serif
         ["variants"] => Array
        (
            [0] => regular
            [1] => italic
        )

    ["subsets"] => Array
        (
            [0] => latin
        )

)@Thamilan

Comment: eval.in/600506@Thamilan

Comment: @Ranjith Please learn how to declare array. The error is in array, not in the foreach. See the error line number. and check the eval now: https://eval.in/600507